# Running python script with cmd file results in ImportError

Tags: python, cmd, importerror

I have a python script named mesh_2.py

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
...
```

If I run it from Spyder with IPython console it works fine. But I want to run it with a cmd (start.cmd) file. It has the following content:

```
cmd /c activate py3.4 && mesh_2.py
```

As I try to run it I get:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I have Anadonda3 installed with a Python 3.4 environment named "py3.4". I am under Windows 7 64 bit.

If I open a cmd.exe myself and write:

```
activate py3.4
python
import numpy as np
```

Then everything is all right and I get no error messages. Does any of you have an idea what am I missing here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As I have written if I activate the environment manually then it does the import. So the package is installed in the virtual environment.

Comment: activate the virtual enviroment, then run your program like `python mesh_2.py`

Comment: The problem is that it needs to be started automatically. That is why I need the cmd script.

Comment: Maybe formatting the command correctly. `cmd /c activate py3.4 && mesh_2.py`. If using quotes they go around items with spaces. See `cmd /?` for help on quotes. The first one is in the wrong position, it was optional anyway..

Comment: OK, you are right. I corrected it. But the error message is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing

```
cmd "/c activate py3.4 && mesh_2.py"
```

with

```
cmd "/c activate py3.4 && python mesh_2.py"
```

Comment: No worries. Got me once or twice too